# DropdownListFor Returns null after HTTP PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

The context of application the is maintaining security orders from Investment Advisors. On a screen where an users amends his orders is the problem appears. In such screen a I have dropdown list to specify the order type whether its a buy or sell and shows values for security, Quantity and price.

**Problem**
I have witnessed while being in an Edit screen, after doing an amendment (Tests have performed not by changing the Buy/Sell but others i.e price). If I performed a HTTP Post, the values of the DropDownList returns null. Refer screenshot:

[image]

Initialization of `SelectList` type

```
public static List<SelectListItem> getBuySellList()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> buySell = new List<SelectListItem>();

            SelectListItem item;

            item = new SelectListItem();
            item.Text = "BUY";
            item.Value = "BUY";
            buySell.Add(item);

            item = new SelectListItem();
            item.Text = "SELL";
            item.Value = "SELL";
            buySell.Add(item);

            return buySell;
        }
```

My Controller as follows:

```
// GET: OrderFlow/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            OrderFlowModel orderFlowModel = db.Find(id);

            ViewData["ORDERFLOW_NO"] = id;
            ViewBag.OrderFlowBuySell = Utility.UtilityDBContext.getBuySellList();

            return View(orderFlowModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(string OrderFlowNo, string OrderFlowSecurityID, string OrderFlowBuySell, string OrderFlowQuantity, string OrderFlowPrice, string OrderFlowTradingDate, string OrderFlowClientAccount, string OrderFlowParticipant, string OrderFlowBuyStatus)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                OrderFlowModel orderFlowModel = new OrderFlowModel();
                orderFlowModel.OrderFlowNo = int.Parse(OrderFlowNo.ToString());
                orderFlowModel.EquityID = OrderFlowSecurityID;
                orderFlowModel.BuySell = OrderFlowBuySell;
                orderFlowModel.Quantity = int.Parse(OrderFlowQuantity);
                orderFlowModel.Price = double.Parse(OrderFlowPrice);

                DateTime dt;
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(OrderFlowTradingDate, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
                {
                    orderFlowModel.TradingDate = dt;
                }
                else orderFlowModel.TradingDate = DateTime.Today;

                orderFlowModel.ClientAccountID = OrderFlowClientAccount;
                orderFlowModel.ParticipantAccountID = OrderFlowParticipant;
                orderFlowModel.Status = OrderFlowBuyStatus;

                try
                {
                    db.Edit(orderFlowModel);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (Exception er)
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = er.Message;
                }

            }

            ViewBag.OrderFlowBuySell = Utility.UtilityDBContext.getBuySellList();
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new{id=OrderFlowNo});
        }
```

The OrderFlow Model:

```
public class OrderFlowModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Order Flow No")]
        public int OrderFlowNo { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Valid Till")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime TradingDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Client A/c ID")]
        public string ClientAccountID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Participant ID")]
        public string ParticipantAccountID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Security is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Security")]
        public string EquityID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Buy or Sell Needs to specify")]
        [Display(Name = "BS")]
        public string BuySell { get; set; }

        [DefaultSettingValue("0")]
        [Display(Name = "Quantity")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}")]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Price")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]
        public double Price { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "User Entered")]
        public string UserEntered { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Effective From")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime EffectiveStart { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Effective Till")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime EffectiveEnd { get; set; }
    }
```

The way I have assigned DropdownListFor in Razor as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BuySell, new SelectList(ViewBag.OrderFlowBuySell, "Text", "Value"), new { @id = "OrderFlowBuySell", @class = "form-control" })
```

HTML output from Browser for the Dropdown List

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Buy or Sell Needs to specify" id="OrderFlowBuySell" name="BuySell"><option selected="selected" value="BUY">BUY</option>
<option value="SELL">SELL</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value that needs to be in your controller method is `BuySell`, this is the selected id of the dropdownlist from your mark-up below (the first parameter):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BuySell, 
       new SelectList(ViewBag.OrderFlowBuySell, "Text", "Value"), 
       new { @id = "OrderFlowBuySell", @class = "form-control" })
```

The `OrderFlowBuySell` is the collection of options that are used to bind the dropdown, in the post you are usually only concerned with the option a user has selected.

Change it to this and the value will be posted:

```
Edit(string OrderFlowNo, string OrderFlowSecurityID, 
    string OrderFlowBuySell, string OrderFlowQuantity, 
    string OrderFlowPrice, string OrderFlowTradingDate, 
    string OrderFlowClientAccount, string OrderFlowParticipant, 
    string OrderFlowBuyStatus, string BuySell)
```

However I would strongly advise you use ViewModels, that way you can just speficy a single object to your controller post.

Comment: @huthonoid Thank You Very much it solved. I am getting Value from BuySell signature. :) For others: I changed my OrderFlow Controller's Edit signature and added `string BuySell` as Hutch mentioned.